# Data transfer from Latch to PIPO

Tags: verilog, modelsim

This program is in Verilog and simulating on Modelsim. I am trying to transfer 48 bits data from 192 bits latch to Parallel in Parallel Out (Register) in 4 slots.

I am not getting output at PIPO. Data is not getting transferred at output of PIPO. For sake for simplicity i have used to transfer 96 bits. Data should come on every 48 sclk and sclk is counted by cnt(counter). The size of PIPO is 48 bits and size of Latch is 192 bits.

```
/*LATCH FOR 192 BITS */ 

Parameter  N= 192;

  always@(xlat,dcsel,sipo_out_gs,rst)

    begin
   if(rst)
 gs_latch <= gs_latch;
   else
 if(xlat == 1)
   gs_latch <= sipo_out_gs;
 else
   gs_latch <= gs_latch;
end
/* 48 BITS DATA FROM LATCH TO PIPO*/

 always@(posedge sclk,posedge rst,cnt)

     begin

     if(rst)
   pipo_lat <= pipo_lat;
 else
   if(cnt >= 47 & cnt <= 94)
   pipo_lat <= gs_latch[47:0];
 end

 always@(posedge sclk,posedge rst,cnt)
    begin
       if(rst)
         pipo_lat <= pipo_lat;
     else
        if(cnt >= 95 && cnt <=142)
          pipo_lat  <= gs_latch[95:48];
     else
       pipo_lat  <= gs_latch[95:48];

   end

 /* counter for grayscale to count upto 192 bits  */ 

   always@(posedge sclk,posedge rst) 
 begin
if(rst) 
  cnt <= 0;
else
  if(cnt != N)
    cnt <= cnt + 1;
  else
    cnt <= 0;
 end
```

Comment: You probably should explicitly mention somewhere in the question that you're talking about an FPGA/verilog

Comment: Its about Verilog doing simulation on modelsim

Comment: Where are your `module` and `endmodule` statements?

Answer (score 1):

Any signal (net/register) for synthesizable code must be assigned in exactly one always block. In the code `pipo_lat` is defined in two separate always blocks. `cnt` should also be removed from the sensitivity list for synchronous logic. Active reset should assign values to a constant. For combination blocks and latch logic, it is better to use `always @*` then putting the full sensitivity list, except you are forced to follow IEEE Std 1364-1995 and nothing newer.

```
module latch_to_pipo #(N=192, M=48, RSTVAL = 1'b0) (
    input wire sclk, rst, xlat,
    input wire [191:0] sipo_out_gs,
    output reg [47:0] pipo_lat );

  reg [7:0]   cnt;
  reg [N-1:0] gs_latch;

  always @* begin // latch
    if(rst)
      gs_latch <= {N{RSTVAL}};
    else if(xlat == 1)
      gs_latch <= sipo_out_gs;
  end

  /* 48 BITS DATA FROM LATCH TO PIPO */
  /* counter for grayscale to count upto 192 bits */
  always @(posedge sclk, posedge rst) begin
    if(rst) begin
      pipo_lat <= {M{RSTVAL}};
      cnt <= 0;
    end
    else begin
      case (cnt)
        8'd47  : pipo_lat <= gs_latch[47:0];
        8'd95  : pipo_lat <= gs_latch[95:48];
        8'd143 : pipo_lat <= gs_latch[143:96];
        8'd191 : pipo_lat <= gs_latch[191:144];
        default: pipo_lat <= pipo_lat;
      endcase
      if(cnt < N-1)
        cnt <= cnt + 1;
      else
        cnt <= 0;
    end
  end
endmodule
```

If your tool supports SystemVerilog, I recommend you your the SV keywords `always_comb`, `always_ff`, `always_latch`, `unique`, `priority`, and other SystemVerilog for design keywords where ever applicable. A good modern simulator/linter/synthesizer will give errors and warnings when common mistakes are make, which is especially usefully for debug. If need be one can always easily degrade to older (and still clean) syntax with a few simple text replacements.

the latest [SystemVerilog LRM](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) available for free from [IEEE](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? (not tested and not 100% cleared)
Note that you don't reset your counter when loading (xlat) the input.  This means you don't know at which time which part of the data will be send out.
Note that the syntesis tool will inferring a latch for the variable 'gs_latch_reg'

```
module cnt
  #(
    parameter N = 192
    )
   (
    input wire rst,
    input wire sclk,
    input wire xlat,
    input wire [191:0] sipo_out_gs,
    output reg [47:0] pipo_lat
    );

   reg [7:0]   cnt;
   reg [191:0] gs_latch;


   always@(xlat,sipo_out_gs,rst, gs_latch)

    begin
       if(rst)
     gs_latch <= gs_latch;
       else
     if(xlat == 1)
       gs_latch <= sipo_out_gs;
     else
       gs_latch <= gs_latch;
    end // always@ (xlat,dcsel,sipo_out_gs,rst)


   /* 48 BITS DATA FROM LATCH TO PIPO*/

   always@(posedge sclk,posedge rst)

     begin

    if(rst)
      pipo_lat <= pipo_lat;
    else
      if(cnt == 47)
        pipo_lat <= gs_latch[47:0];
          else if(cnt == 95)
            pipo_lat  <= gs_latch[95:48];
          else if(cnt == 143)
            pipo_lat  <= gs_latch[143:96];
          else if(cnt == 191)
            pipo_lat  <= gs_latch[191:144];
      else
        pipo_lat  <= pipo_lat;
     end

   /* counter for grayscale to count upto 192 bits  */ 

   always @(posedge sclk,posedge rst) 
     begin
    if(rst) 
       cnt <= 0;
    else
      if(cnt != N)
        cnt <= cnt + 1;
      else
        cnt <= 0;
     end

endmodule
```